# Explicit description of SU(2,2)/U

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Consider the real diagonal $4\times 4$ - matrix
$$I_{2,2}={\rm diag}(1,1,-1,-1)$$ 
and  the corresponding special unitary group
$$ G={\rm SU}(2,2)=\{g\in {\rm SL}(4,{\mathbb{C}})\ |\ g\cdot I_{2,2}\cdot \bar g ^{\rm tr}=I_{2,2}\}.$$
We regard $G$ as an algebraic group over ${\mathbb{R}}$.
It is known that $G$ is quasi-split, that is, $G$ contains a Borel subgroup $B$ defined over ${\mathbb{R}}$.
Let $U$ denote the unipotent radical of $B$, it is defined over ${\mathbb{R}}$. 
Set $X=G/U$.

> **Question.** *How can one describe the homogeneous space  $X$* ***explicitly*** *(by equations and "inequalities") as a quasi-projective variety over ${\mathbb{R}}$ on which ${\rm SU}(2,2)$ naturally acts?*

EDIT: I explain why I need explicit equations for $G/U$. I want to *twist* the desired variety by the 1-cocycle $c=I_{2,2}\in G(\mathbb{R})_2$ and to obtain explicit equations for the twisted variety $Y={}_c X$. 
This new variety $Y$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is a homogeneous space of the twisted group $_cG={\rm SU}(4)$ for which $U$ is the stabilizer of a $\mathbb C$-point. 
Of course, $Y$ has no $\mathbb R$-points, because the stabilizer of an $\mathbb R$-point would be a compact form of $U$, but we know that the unipotent group $U$ has no compact forms.

Comment: Explicit could also mean identifying it as an orbit of some linear representation, or the same at a projective level?

Comment: @YCor: I don't know what a projective level means.

Comment: @YCor: Yes,  I would be happy to see $X$ as an orbit in a linear representation, but I would like to see equations and inequalities defining $X$.

Comment: I mean orbit in the corresponding action on $P(V)$ for some $G$-module $V$. This can always been achieved, while being an orbit in $V$ itself can be achieved only if $X$ is quasi-affine.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I would be happy to see the equations and inequalities with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ defining $X$ as an orbit in $P(V)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your variety is just the variety of pairs of ${\mathbb C}$-linearly independent vectors in ${\mathbb C}^4$ that are isotropic with respect to this Hermitian form and orthogonal to each other. Respectively, the twisted form is the same variety but for another Hermitian form (and if the form is not hyperbolic, there is no such a pair over ${\mathbb R}$, as you mentioned).

Comment: Let $Y$ denote the variety of pairs of ${\mathbb C}$-linearly independent vectors in ${\mathbb C}^4$ that are isotropic with respect to this Hermitian form and orthogonal to each other. By Witt's theorem on Hermitian forms, the group ${\rm SU}(2,2)$ acts transitively on $Y({\mathbb R})$.

Comment: However, a calculation shows that the stabilizer in ${\rm SU}(2,2)$ of a point of $Y$ has dimension 4, while the dimension of $U$ is $(15-3)/2=6$.

Comment: Yes, I was not quite accurate. The actual variety is as follows: you choose an isotropic vector $v$ in ${\mathbb C}^4$, and then another isotropic vector $u$ in ${\mathbb C}v^{\perp}/{\mathbb C}v$ with respect to the induced form on this $2$-dimensional ${\mathbb C}$-vector space.

Comment: Your answer in comments seems to be correct, but for  $G={\rm U}(2,2)$ rather than for $G={\rm SU}(2,2)$. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question has been answered in comments (by Victor Petrov), I prefer to post an answer.
I assume that $G={\rm U}(2,2)$ rather than $G={\rm SU}(2,2)$.

1. My variety $G/U$ is the variety $X$ whose real points are  the triples
   $$(W,w,b),$$
   where $W\subset \mathbb C^4$ is an *isotropic* 2-dimensional subspace, $w\in W$ a nonzero vector (which is automatically isotropic),
   and $b$ is a  nonzero element of $\Lambda^2W$.
   This variety is a $R_{\mathbb C/\mathbb R}\mathbb G_{m,\mathbb C}^2$-torsor over the variety $\mathcal F$ of *isotropic flags*: the map is
   $$X\to\mathcal F\colon\quad (W,w,b)\mapsto (W,\langle w\rangle),$$
   and the action of $(\mathbb C^\times)^2$ on $X$ is
   $$ (\lambda,\mu)*(W,w,b)=(W,\lambda w,\lambda\mu b)\quad \text{for } \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb C^\times.$$
   By Witt's theorem for Hermitian forms, $G(\mathbb R)$ transitively acts on $X(\mathbb R)$, and my calculations show
   that the stabilizer of the point  $$(\langle e_1,e_2\rangle, e_1, e_1\wedge e_2)\in X(\mathbb R)$$
   is a maximal unipotent subgroup of $G$.
   Thus $X\simeq G/U$.
   The twisted form of $X$ is the same variety, but for another Hermitian form (and if the form is not hyperbolic, there is no such  triples $(W,w,b)$ over $\mathbb R$, as Victor has mentioned).
2. The real points of the  variety $\mathcal V$ of Victor's *answer* are pairs of non-proportional isotropic vectors
   $(w_1,w_2)$ in $\mathbb C^4$.
   This variety  is a $R_{\mathbb C/\mathbb R}\mathbb G_{a,\mathbb C}$-torsor over  $X$:  the map is
   $$\mathcal V\to X\colon\quad (w_1,w_2)\mapsto
   (\,\langle w_1,w_2\rangle,\, w_1,\, w_1\wedge w_2)$$
   and the action of  $\mathbb C$ on $\mathcal V$ is
   $$a*(w_1,w_2)=(w_1, w_2+aw_1)\quad\text{for } a\in\mathbb C.$$
3. The real points of the variety $\mathcal V'$ of Victor's *comment* is the set of pairs $(v,u)$, where $v$ is a nonzero isotropic vector in $\mathbb C^4$,
   and $u$ is a nonzero vector in $v^\perp/\langle v \rangle$ that is isotropic with respect to the induced Hermitian form on $v^\perp$.
   We construct a $G$-equivariant  isomorphism $$\varphi\colon\mathcal V'\to X.$$
   Let $(v,u)\in \mathcal V'(\mathbb R)$. We lift $u$ to an isotropic vector $\tilde u\in \mathbb C^4$ and set
   $$\varphi(v,u)=(\langle v, \tilde u\rangle, v, v\wedge\tilde u)\in X(\mathbb R).$$
   In the opposite direction, if we have  $(W,w,b)\in X(\mathbb R)$, we choose $y\in W$ such that $b=w\wedge y$, and we set
   $$\psi(W,w,b)=(w, y+\langle w\rangle)\in\mathcal V'(\mathbb R).$$
   Since $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are mutually inverse, we see that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.